# notification service extension on SwiftUI app protocol not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, push-notification

I’m trying to implement a NotificationService extension on a SwiftUI app protocol (iOS 16). Regular push notification works, I’m submitting the hasMutableContent flag (true) when creating the push notification on the server.

In Xcode for the iOS App I've selected `File -> new -> Target`, it created the `NotificationService` and `info.plist` files. I’ve set some breakpoints inside the new generated class `NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension` but they are never reached. The breakpoints get a blue dotted outline. The deployment target is set to 16.4 in Xcode, my connected device is on 16.5.1.
In the main app file, I had to do some extra work to get access to appDelegate e.g.

```swift
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
```

Do I need some extra work for the `NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension` as well?

1. Under Targets, my app's target -> `Build Phases` -> `Embed Foundation Extension` -> `Copy only when installing` is unchecked, the Notification service is also listed in here.

**Points 2. and 3. are not needed**

2. I've changed the `Target Membership` of the generated `NotificationService` file, now two checkboxes are active, for the Notification itself (by default active) and I checked in here the main app. The breakpoints are not blue dotted anymore.
3. I copied the content of the generated `Info.plist` into my apps `Info.plist`.

**Breakpoint issue: see Gruntcakes comment below**

Unfortunately the breakpoints are still not reached. I guess the issue could be related to the fact that this is a SwiftUI app, using the newer SwiftUI App protocol where you got the @main annotation.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
```

But what do I have to do, to get the `NotificationService extension` to work?

Comment: The extension is in a separate process to the app, you can't run the extension and set breakpoints if you run the app. Did you actually try to *run* the extension as opposed to running the app in order to hit breakpoints? Search how to run/debug extensions.

Comment: @Gruntcakes ouhh that's a good point, didn't think about that. I still had a stupid mistake down the function call chain, the mutable-content flag wasn't set and default value was used. Now it works, but yes, the breakpoints are not catching. Will look that up, thanks

Comment: @Leo was the only problem the mutable-content flag in the notification payload?  I can't get my service extension to work, even with the content flag set on a new swiftUI generic app.

Comment: @smakus yes that was my only issue for me. I guess your regular (unmodified) push notification is working without any issues? If that's the case, File > New > Target > Search Notification Service Extension (dialog appears to activate the target extension, just choose to Cancel). Also make sure you minimum Deployment Target version is correct for both, the main app target and the notification service target. Don't chase a ghost, like myself (setting breakpoints etc. in the notification service file). Xcode will create the file with bestAttemptContent etc. This should modify your notification.

Comment: @smakus also the points 2. and 3. from my initial post above are not needed. I've reset that to default. Don't know if that could cause some issues, but definitely not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Write down this code, run and put breakpoint on the notificationService class then once notification landing on the app, it lands in this class, just replace your notification service class with following code and run code, hopefully it will solve your problem.

for reference you can also see this link

https://medium.com/gits-apps-insight/processing-notification-data-using-notification-service-extension-6a2b5ea2da17

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        debugPrint(request.content)
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title )"
            if let attachment = request.attachment{
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
            }
            
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}

extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        
//        guard let fcmOptions = content.userInfo["fcm_options"] as? [String:Any] else {return nil}
        
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["image"] as? String, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already a `class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension`, and have a breakpoint literally in the first line of its `didReceive(...)` func. So if my file isn't called at all, what makes you think blindly overriding my file with yours would change anything? btw. I've read that medium post already, but there is still something missing I think, when using SwiftUI app protocol (or misconfigured).